# ng-click not working in jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jinja2

I am trying to pass jinja variable in angular ng-click function `getMenuById('{{restaurant.id}}', '{{restaurant.name}}')`. But after page rendered `ng-click` not working. I have tried to print on console but didn't work. Below is the Jinja template file where I am passing jinja variable in `ng-click` and also I have changed the angular interpolate symbol with square brackets( [[ ]]).

restaurant.html

```
{% for restaurant in restaurant_details %}
<div class="col-md-12" ng-if="serverSideRender">
    <article class="box">
        <figure class="animated fadeInRight" data-animation-type="fadeInRight" data-animation-delay="0.3" style="animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 0.3s; visibility: visible;">
            <a class="hover-effect" title="" href="/restaurant/{{restaurant.id}}">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="{{restaurant.images[0].image_url}}">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="pull-right rating-container">
                <strong>{{ restaurant.rating }}
                <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <h2 class="box-title" style="font-size:24px">
                <strong>
                <a href="/restaurant/{{restaurant.id}}">{{ restaurant.name }}</a>
                </strong>
            </h2>
            <div>
                <small>
                <strong> {{restaurant.city}} </strong>
                </small>
            </div>
            <div class="restaurant-address">
                {{restaurant.address}}
            </div>
            <div class="restaurant-details">
                <span class="detail-title">Cuisines : </span>
                {% for association in restaurant.association %}
                <span>
                <strong>{{association.cuisines.cuisine}} {% if loop.index != restaurant.association|length
                %}
                <span>,</span>
                {% endif %}
                </strong>
                </span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="restaurant-details">
                <span class="detail-title">Cost for two : </span>
                <span>
                <strong>₹ {{restaurant.price}}</strong>
                </span>
                <!-- <span ng-repeat="association in restaurant.association">
                    <strong>association.cuisines.cuisine]] <span ng-if="$index != restaurant.association.length - 1" >,</span></strong>
                    </span> -->
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a href="tel:{{restaurant.phone}}" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> call</a>
                <div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getMenuById('{{restaurant.id}}', '{{restaurant.name}}')">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> view menu
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

restaurant.js

```
$scope.getMenubyId = function (restaurantId, restaurantName) {

    $scope.restaurantName = restaurantName;

    $http.get("/api/v1/restaurant/dish?restaurant_id=" + restaurantId)
      .then(function (res) {
        $scope.restaurantDish = res.data.result.dish;
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: what if you just put `{{ restaurant.id }}` into a `<pre>` tag, does it populate?

Comment: @mmenschig jinja convert to its value.

`<pre>{{restaurant.id}}</pre>` give me id value which is 15.

Comment: can u create a playground by procduing this isse

Comment: @SaEChowdary suggest any playground. can't find on google.

Comment: plunker,jsfiddle

Comment: @SaEChowdary can I use jinja there? Because I think it is the frontend side playground.